# C++ - How to update pointer (or members) between instances of same class

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a simple class which consists of a `void` pointer and an `int` (this is some sort of a `boost::Variant` educational project).
I also have a working copy constructor and a destructor.

But what grinds my gears is, how I would accomplish something like this:

```
Container cont1("some value"); //simple construction
Container cont2;
cont2.createLink(cont1); //this should initialize members with a reference (or something alike)
std::cout<<cont1; //yields "some value"

cont2.set(20); //setting this container should update the original container too, since I initialized with a reference (or smth alike)
std::cout<<cont1; //yields 20
```

This is the simplified version of the class:

```
class Container {
    public:
        Container(){}
        Container(const std::string &val){var.type = STRING; var.data = new std::string(val);}
        Container(int val){ /* same for int */}
        Container(const Container &val){ /* do a memory copy */}

        void set(int val){ /* set the value if type matches, otherwise allocate a new pointer */}
        void set(const std::string &val){ /* the same as for int */}
        void createLink(const Container &val){ /* somehow assign a reference or whatsoever */}
    private:
        typedef struct VAR {
            int type = 0;
            void *data = NULL; }       
        VAR var;
}
```

If I set the value of `cont2` to a `string` (i.e. the same data type it holds at the moment), everything is fine, because the set would not allocate a new pointer and rather assign a new value.
But how do I  make sure the pointer of `cont1` updates if I assign a different value to `cont2` and therefore have to allocate a new pointer?

Would I need something like `shared_pointer`?

Thanks for any insight!

**EDIT:**

I changed to function name to make it more clear what should happen.

Comment: If I saw in production code `cont2.set(cont1);` I would not think that `cont2` and `cont1` are now linked together.  I think you should have a `set_link()` function to do that.  then when you want to assign `20` to both you would call an `update_value()` function or something like that.

Comment: Well you're right, I should change the function name to reflect this, but nevertheless I don't even know how to accomplish this.

Comment: Should _all_ instances of `Container` share the same data? In that case, simply use `static` member variables (a.k.a. class variables).

Comment: @rwong I will look into this, thanks!

Comment: @underscore_d No, only if they are explicitly set to do that.

Comment: I'd have to know more about what you need to accomplish and how this is being used, but it seems to me like I'd be iffy about what you are trying to accomplish with this class. Either way, a shared pointer to the data and shared pointer to the integer type would probably be the easiest way for you to handle this. Just make sure you write the copy/move constructor/assignment operators correctly.

Comment: @jxh This is a typo, sorry.

Comment: @RyanP Essentially I'm trying to implement type erasure on my own (I don't wanted to copy some code, I want to understand it...) with some additional features I find interesting.

Comment: I really don't get what do you try to accomplish with createLink?

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution that only involves straight OO. You could create an interface for your variant type, and use double indirection to the variant instance to allow linked containers to share the same variant instance.

The reason double indirection is required is because of the way you want the `set()` method to automatically allocate a new variant instance if the new type doesn't match the original type. If we simply shared a pointer to the variant from both containers, then after `set()` creates a new variant instance, each container would be referring to different instances again.

To get around that, we can use a pointer to a pointer to a variant in the container instead.

Here is a possible way to define your variant interface, and how it could be subclassed:

```
typedef std::ostream Out;
struct BadType {};

struct Var {
    virtual ~Var () = default;
    virtual Out & print (Out &os) { return os << "(BadType)"; }
    virtual void set (int) { throw BadType(); }
    virtual void set (const std::string &) { throw BadType(); }
};

struct VarInteger : Var {
    int data;
    VarInteger (int v) : data(v) {}
    Out & print (Out &os) { return os << data; }
    void set (int v) throw() { data = v; }
};

struct VarString : Var {
    std::string data;
    VarString (const std::string &v) : data(v) {}
    Out & print (Out &os) { return os << data; }
    void set (const std::string &v) throw() { data = v; }
};
```

Here is how you could define your pointer to pointer, and how they could be initialized:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Var> VarPtr;
std::shared_ptr<VarPtr> varptr_;

static VarPtr make_var () { return std::make_shared<Var>(); }
static VarPtr make_var (int v) { return std::make_shared<VarInteger>(v); }
static VarPtr make_var (const std::string &v) {
    return std::make_shared<VarString>(v);
}

VarPtr & var () { return *varptr_; }
const VarPtr & var () const { return *varptr_; }

Container () : varptr_(std::make_shared<VarPtr>(make_var())) {}
Container (int v) : varptr_(std::make_shared<VarPtr>(make_var(v))) {}
Container (const std::string &v)
    : varptr_(std::make_shared<VarPtr>(make_var(v))) {}
```

And here is how your `set()` methods and `createLink()` method could be implemented.

```
void set (int v) {
    try { var()->set(v); }
    catch (BadType) { var() = make_var(v); }
}

void set (const std::string &v) {
    try { var()->set(v); }
    catch (BadType) { var() = make_var(v); }
}

void createLink (const Container &val) { varptr_ = val.varptr_; }
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](http://ideone.com/VYdubh)

Answer (score 0):

How about the following. Of course `createLink` cannot not take a const reference so I made it to take a non-const pointer.

```
class Container {
    const int STRING    = 0x0000001;
    const int INT       = 0x0000002;

    const int LINK      = 0x8000000;

public:
    ...    
    void set(int val){...}
    void set(const std::string &val)
    { 
        if (var.type == LINK) 
        {
            reinterpret_cast<Container*>(var.data)->set(val);
        }
        else
            ...
    }
    void createLink(Container* val)
    {
        var.data = val;
        var.type = LINK;
    }
private:
    typedef struct VAR {
        int type = 0;
        void *data = NULL;
    };
    VAR var;
};
```

There are a some important points to think about - relative lifetimes of the link and the linked is the most obvious one.